# MySQL three table query or union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, they have a common field `user_id`

**gain_table**

```
+--------------------------+
|user_id    |   gain_count |
| 1         |   3          |
| 2         |   4          |
| 3         |   1          |
+--------------------------+
```

**consume_table**

```
+--------------------------+
|user_id    |consume_count |
| 2         |   5          |
| 5         |   4          |
| 6         |   7          |
+--------------------------+
```

**join_table**

```
+--------------------------+
|user_id    |   join_count |
| 1         |   3          |
| 2         |   1          |
| 5         |   4          |
+--------------------------+
```

I want get output like this:

**Output:**

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+------------+
|user_id    |   gain_count |consume_count | join_count |
| 1         |   3          |     0        | 3          |
| 2         |   4          |     5        | 1          |
| 3         |   1          |     0        | 0          |
| 5         |   0          |     4        | 4          |
| 6         |   0          |     7        | 0          |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

Yes, I want these three table to union as one table, and if some field value is empty then give 0 to this field value.

How to write MySQL query?

Comment: I believe it would be a simple JOIN between the tree tables and then figure out how to coalesce the null values into zero.

Comment: how to use join?The problem is empty value can lead to record lose because join condition.

Comment: show up, whatever you tried.

Comment: You need a `FULL JOIN`, which has been part of the ansi sql standard since 1992 and every major database but mysql has supported since at least 2000. Without that, you'll have to do a bunch of extra work to get around that limitation.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn how to use `FULL JOIN` in mysql

Comment: You don't. MySql doesn't have it. You have to write a much larger and less efficient query instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the result you want with a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) of all the tables, selecting 0 for non-existent values in each table and then summing all fields by `user_id`:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(gain_count) AS gain_count, 
    SUM(consume_count) AS consume_count, SUM(join_count) AS join_count
FROM (SELECT user_id, gain_count, 0 AS consume_count, 0 AS join_count FROM gain_table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT user_id, 0, consume_count, 0 FROM consume_table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT user_id, 0, 0, join_count FROM join_table) u
GROUP BY user_id
```

Output:

```
user_id     gain_count  consume_count   join_count
1           3           0               3
2           4           5               1
3           1           0               0
5           0           4               4
6           0           7               0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with ansi-standard sql:

```
SELECT coalesce(g.user_id, c.user_id, j.user_id) user_id
    , coalesce(g.gain_count, 0) gain_count
    , coalesce(c.consume_count, 0) consume_count
    , coalesce(j.join_count,0) join_count
FROM gain_table g
FULL JOIN consume_table c on c.user_id = g.user_id
FULL JOIN join_table j on j.user_id = coalsece(c.user_id, g.user_id)
```

This has been part of the ansi standard since 92 release, and every major database but MySql can do it. MySql has to do this instead:

```
SELECT ids.user_id
    , coalesce(g.gain_count, 0) gain_count
    , coalesce(c.consume_count, 0) consume_count
    , coalesce(j.join_count, 0) join_count
FROM (
    SELECT user_id FROM gain_table
    UNION
    SELECT user_id FROM consume_table
    UNION
    SELECT user_id FROM join_table
) ids
LEFT JOIN gain_table g on g.user_id = ids.user_id
LEFT JOIN consume_table c on c.user_id = ids.user_id
LEFT JOIN join_table j on j.user_id = ids.user_id
```